# Jetpack Compose LazyVerticalGrid: How to apply horizontal padding for each row except 1st row?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to show grid layout which have following 2 requirements:

1. 1st row should have no horizontal padding
2. All other rows should have horizontal padding

I can't add padding to LazyVerticalGrid because it will fail 1st requirement.
I can't add padding to each item as the padding should be for each row, not item.

This is the code:

```kotlin
Scaffold { padding ->
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(300.dp),
        contentPadding = padding,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
    ) {
        item(span = { GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan) }) {
            // LazyRow: should have no horizontal padding
        }

        items(list, key = { it.uuid }) { item ->
            // horizontal padding required for each row
        }
    }
}
```